# I need help with my shopping

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay

This is my shopping list:

> A chocolate bar,
>   some meat that's raw,
>   something cheap,
>   and an apple core.

Will you help me?

Hint

> To help answer the question, you could seek the assistance of a doctor that prescribes questionable treatments.

Update: The puzzle has almost been completed by Rand al'Thor. Here is a hint for the final step:

> Stop being so nice.

Update #2: I've accepted the answer, although the last step was not completed. The answer to the final question, "will you help me?", was:

> Nay (neigh)

Comment: "cheap" is an anagram of "peach", but there are no particularly compelling anagrams of the others, unless you're buying *brothel cacao* and a *cereal pop* to go with that peach in your shopping basket.

Comment: It appears anagrams can't help. Is there something else about the word "cheap"? Perhaps the aforementioned doctor provides a clue.

Comment: I assume the hint refers to a rot13(dhnpx), but can't see how that's useful ...

Comment: It's difficult to say more without giving the game away. What kind of a word is rot13(dhnpx)? Are there similar words here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Potential answer:

> the last word of each line of the puzzle is a homophonic reference to the noise made by an animal.

More specifically:

> A chocolate **bar** --> baa (sheep)
>  some meat that's **raw** --> roar (lion)
>  something **cheap** --> cheep (chick)
>  and an apple **core** --> caw (crow).

Of course, this fits perfectly with the hint:

> "a doctor that prescribes questionable treatments" is a **quack** (duck).

The OP says I still need to figure out the last line: "*Will you help me?*"

> I'm a bit stumped here. Is it as simple as "go to a zoo" to find these animals? Maybe "Will you help **me(w)**" --> cat?

Comment: Oh, of course! And the doctor must be Dr. Dolittle, who  -- judging by his name -- wouldn't be very helpful.

Comment: ...Oh, or that works too.

Comment: You are almost there! You just need to answer the question posed: Will you help me???

Comment: @Statman Oh, I didn't even realise that bit was meaningful ... edited with a couple of guesses, but I'm probably still missing something.

Comment: Perhaps Rot13(lvc yvxr n sbk)? Even living in the countryside, I can't think of any closer than that...

Comment: @Fifth_H0r5eman You're on the right lines...

Comment: @Randal'Thor read the question out loud, and look at item number 1.

Comment: @JeffUK I'm not sure where you're going with that, but it's the wrong direction. Fifth_H0r5eman's suggestion is on the right path.

Comment: I'll put it in an answer so I can spoiler it

Comment: rot13(lbh uryc => lryc, sbk), maybe?

Comment: @OnlyF Nope, it's more obvious than that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes

> Ewe will help you, it will be able to give you a chocolate baa

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Good attempt, but the answer fits better with the rest of the puzzle.